# Is it possible to use "sequentially" with the singular?

Tags: adverbs

[image]

I am trying to describe the structure shown in the image. My example is as follows:

> The string is wound on the bobbin **sequentially** from the left to
>   the right.

As far as I searched, it seems that "sequentially" is usually used with the plural.  Is the usage of "sequentially" in my example correct?

Comment: You might want to read this about windings: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/transformer-basics.html Sequentially is an adverb and has nothing to do with singular and plural.

Comment: seems fine to me. Reading this, I'd think that the windings are sequential.

Comment: I don't really like the use of *sequentially* here because I don't think it adds anything, and it confuses the sentence.  What's wrong with just "is wound on the bobbin from left to right"?

Comment: I don't think **sequentially** is apt.

Comment: Exactly, windings are sequential but normally one needn't say it. Wound from left to right is enough. a left-to-right winding.

Comment: The string is wound on the bobbin **evenly** from the left to the right. The next layer is wound evenly from right to left, and so (pun *sew*) on.

Comment: I would use *continuously*.  Or just *wound*. *sequentially* is redundant because *not sequentially* by your meaning would be a mess.

Comment: Weather Vane uses the word "layer".  Is it possible to say that the string is wound in layers on the bobbin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your question: *Is it possible to use “sequentially” with the singular?***

**Your example:** *The string is wound on the bobbin sequentially from the left to the right.*

There is nothing wrong with using *sequentially* for the reason you ask. *Sequentially* is defined as "*forming or following a logical order or sequence*" so it doesn't matter that you are writing instructions about a singular item if you are a referring to *multiple steps*.

**However, the word is out of place in your example** because the verb *wound* is the past particle of *wind* which aptly describes the ongoing action of winding the thread. Winding is a continuous circular motion, so "sequentially" does not aptly describe the action because technically there is only one ongoing step.

Comment: Except that you start with one end of the the string (or the bobbin) and stop once you reach the other end. The circular motion continues until it can't any more ;) (Still, the sentence would sound better if the string *was wound* or *should be wound* or *has been wound*. I don't think that *sequentially* is an issue.)

Comment: @jasonbassford "winding" refers to the motion, not the string. You could wind a handle, that wouldn't run out.

Comment: Yes, but when I *wind* a string, I always think of it as a single 360° rotation. Which means that it's perfectly understandable to me to "wind a string around something twice" (and sequentially)—meaning that I have made two such complete motions. Those motions can be in sequence. (And, yes, I could say "complete winding motion" instead, but the meaning is clear without that exact level of detail.)